# Azure WebJob Schedule error - Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, azure, publish, schedule, webjob

I am new to Azure. I am trying to deploy a simple c#.Net console Application to Azure via VS2015. When, in Solution Explorer, I right click the solution name and select 'Publish as Azure Webjob', it gives me object reference error. I tried creating a new console app from scratch and publish it, but still same error.
I also tried running VS in admin mode. But no success. 
It says:

Publish succeeded. 
Creating the scheduler job  Error:An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Due to this none of my web jobs are running on a schedule. Please help! thank you

Comment: what's the version Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish nugget you are using now? do you try to update it or your Azure SDK?

Comment: Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish version is v1.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me please your service plan? Is running in free tier? If yes, you can not set the recurrence in minutes. As MS describes here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/

one can deploy with all frequencies other than those defined in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem also, in my case the schedule start/end dates were both set to the past.

Alternatively comment out almost everything and set the job to 
    "runMode": "OnDemand"